# Add checkbox in task Page In inno-setup and make it work according to checkbox

Tags: checkbox, task, inno-setup

How to add checkbox in task page in inno setup and make it work as checked or unchecked:

- Install Visual C++

I have Tried-

```
  [Tasks] 
 Name: desktopicon; Description: {cm:CreateDesktopIcon}; GroupDescription: {cm:AdditionalIcons} 
 Name: vcredist_x64; Description: Install Visual C++; Flags: unchecked   
  [Code] 
 procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep); 
 begin 
   if CurStep = ssPostInstall then 
   begin 
   var 
   ResultCode: Integer;
 begin
     if IsTaskSelected('vcredist_x64') then 
   begin 
       Status.Caption:='Installing Visual C++...';    
       Exec(ExpandConstant('{src}\Redist\vcredist_x64.exe'),'/q',false)
```

But it showing some error `Identifier expected`

I am very new to inno-setup and here (stackoverflow.com). Can anybody help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you want is possible, but that's what the built-in [`[Tasks]`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=taskssection) section is for. Are you sure you want to put that check box on the components page ?

Comment: We would, but it's hard to understand what you're asking for. What specific problem you're stucked on. The requirements you listed are too broad. Stack Overflow doesn't work that way. We are not writing projects on request. We are answering questions on specific problems, so try to focus on one specific problem you have.

Comment: The `[Tasks]` section creates those check boxes. What you are probably missing now is the connection to the entries that will be conditionally processed (created, installed or executed depending on the section where they are used). That's what the [`Tasks`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=componentstasksparams&anchor=Tasks) parameter is for. For example to conditionally install a file, you would write in the `[Files]` section e.g. `Source: "MyApp.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Tasks: installapp` when having in `[Tasks]` an entry like `Name: installapp; Description: Install my app.`

Comment: I wrote that as a generic example. The `[Files]` section is for installing files, so the vcredist_x64.exe files has been copied to the selected installation folder if that task check box was checked. What you are installing are so called prerequisites which should be installed from the `[Code]` section's `PrepareToInstall` event and should not be available for users as optional tasks to install. Consider what happens if the user decides to uncheck e.g. DirectX task and has not minimum version of DirectX needed for running your app.

Comment: Here is the [`basic skeleton`](http://pastebin.com/74028p0E) for installing prerequisites based on selected tasks.

Comment: The reason why I suggested to use `PrepareToInstall` event is that it installs prerequisites before the installation of the application. The reason for that is simple, the installation of a prerequisite may fail. What will you do if the installation succeeds but the installation of, say DirectX will fail ? The user will have your application but won't be able to run it. Well, if you don't care about this, you can use e.g. the `[Run]` section instead of that event. For hiding the installers refer to their manuals, e.g. VC runtime has `/q` parameter as far as I remember.

Comment: The `[Tasks]` section only defines task check boxes. It doesn't execute, or install anything, just defines those check boxes. And those you can connect to any of the `[Run]`, `[Files]`, `[Registry]` or other section entries through the `Tasks` parameter. So you can use `[Run]` section, just put in the proper entry the `Tasks` parameter for corresponding task, e.g. `Tasks: vcredist_x64`. How to pass parameters in the `[Run]` section is clearly described in help, so I would refer you there.

Comment: I don't know. Try to search the web for `<product> silent install`. I believe that for all you'll find the answer...

Comment: Variable declarations (`var` block) must be placed after the method prototype but before its first `begin`. You could see that in gazillion code examples all over the Internet. Except that you've made from this question  a moving target and that unaccept did not make me happy, so I'm done here ;-)

Comment: @TLama I am  very sorry that ,you misunderstand me,as i am new here i was just experimenting and i mistakenly doubled clicked the accepted answer tag.So please forgive me.

Comment: @TLama I am not good in pascal scripting,can you modify the script and post the answer again.Please

Comment: There you go http://pastebin.com/drBCARvu. But we both could save some time just if you look into help. There are examples as well. Programming is not a trial/error process.

Comment: @Tlama  Thanks for helping.Post this as answer so i can make this question as answered.And _Sorrrrrrry again for my previous mistake_.

Comment: @TLama  I am just testing the script,but it showing  `Identifier expected` for `Status`,Oh yes `status.Caption` is, when  you install C++ it should be shown instead of Extracting files.What i should do?

Comment: @Tlama are you still angry to me please if not then post a answer, I will make that as accepted.Please

Comment: It's not about anger, or anything personal here :) It's just my laziness to write another answer to a question after such radical change. My answer that I've posted here (and which I've deleted later on) was about what the `[Tasks]` section is (which took me some time to write because I'm trying to take my role here seriously). So sorry, I don't want to spend another time on writing a different post about a variable block misplacement. More useful for others (as that's the main purpose of this site) would be that talk about the `[Tasks]` section.

Comment: Besides, a code that you chose to use could have been simply executed from the `[Run]` section, or properly from the `PrepareToInstall` event, before the actual installation with no option for users to not install any of the necessary prerequisites. I mean, you should not install prerequisites after the installation itself, and you should not allow users to choose whether they want them or not (if your app. requires them to run). P.S. you are free to answer and accept your own questions ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THIS IS THE ANSWER FOR MY QUESTION

Credit Goes To *TLama*

```
Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

#define MyAppName "My Program"
#define MyAppVersion "1.5"
#define MyAppPublisher "My Company, Inc."
#define MyAppURL "http://www.example.com/"
#define MyAppExeName "MyProg.exe"

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application.
; Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{49AA44CB-55C1-47D3-9B89-84D4A1271A8D}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
DefaultDirName={pf}\{#MyAppName}
DefaultGroupName={#MyAppName}
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
OutputBaseFilename=Setup
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes

[Languages]
Name: english; MessagesFile: compiler:Default.isl
[Tasks]
Name: desktopicon; Description: {cm:CreateDesktopIcon};GroupDescription: {cm:AdditionalIcons}; Flags: unchecked
Name: vcredist_x64; Description: Install Visual C++; Flags: unchecked

[Files]
Source: C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5\Examples\MyProg.exe; DestDir: {app}; Flags: ignoreversion
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Icons]
Name: {group}\{#MyAppName}; Filename: {app}\{#MyAppExeName}
Name: {commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}; Filename: {app}\{#MyAppExeName};Tasks: desktopicon

[Run]
Filename: {src}\redist\vcredist_x64.exe; Parameters: /q; StatusMsg: Installing Visual C++...; Tasks: vcredist_x64
```